i get error ERROR solana_net_utils] Received no response at tcp/8899, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on receive operation
I received this error while starting the validator node, I checked and these ports are not in use. Does anyone know how to fix this error?


You might need to configure port forwarding in your router. Here is an example of what your NAT rule should look like:
General:

Chain: dstnat
Protocol: tcp
Dst. Port: 8899

Action:

Action: dst-nat
To Addresses: [Your RPC node's internal IP address]
To Ports: 8899


You could consider the following steps to bind your RPC and to update the firewall.
example:

sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/solana-validator.service 

....service/config settings:

  --rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 \ 
  --rpc-port 8899 \

Remember to :
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart solana-validator

Make sure to also allow the firewall and port rules.
example:

sudo ufw status
sudo ufw allow 8000:8020/udp
sudo ufw allow 8000:8899/udp

Hope it helps.
